# Set the value of a <select> element in D3?

Tags: d3.js

How can I set the value of a `<select>` element, using D3.js?

I'm trying this:

```
d3.select('#myselect').attr('value', 'France');
```

But it isn't working.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/06z9tnzs/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use **property** instead of **attr** for setting the value.

`d3.select('#myselect').property('value', 'France');`

From the d3 docs:

> Some HTML elements have special properties that are not addressable using standard attributes or styles. For example, form text fields have a value string property, and checkboxes have a checked boolean property. You can use the property operator to get or set these properties, or any other addressable field on the underlying element, such as className.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#property

Albert's comments are also correct regarding your JSFiddle missing the d3.js reference and not specifying the id of "myselect" on the **select** element.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed both in the JSFiddle and now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/06z9tnzs/3/

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but is it because you did not include d3.js?

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I can't see it in the frame source for some reason. 
Also,
select should have a id of myselect

```
<select>
    <option value="England">England</option>
    <option id = "myselect" value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to set value by d3.js

`d3.select('#myselect').node().value = 'France';`